# Open problems epsilon nets

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, reference-request, machine-learning

What would be a good source for open problems for (weak) epsilon nets? Is there a good survey / recent article that summarizes recent advancements on the  topic?

Comment: Could you clarify to which definition of epsilon nets you are referring?

Comment: Seems to be something about "machine learning" according to the tag...

Comment: You can find the definition in this post of Gil Kalai: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/04/22/gil-kalai-the-weak-epsilon-net-problem/. The original definition can be found in this article: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=884223